# How to execute parallel run in postman for get option in one go?

Tags: api-testing, postman

Need to know how to run parallel executions in postman for get options with single access id but with multiple requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman doesn't have a parallel runner option. With [Newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman), a command-line harness for Postman, you can run your Postman tests in parallel as long as they are in a collection.

You can find an example script to run a Postman collection in parallel at: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/examples/parallel-collection-runs.js